# How to execute an action before close metro app WinJS

Tags: javascript, winjs

I want to trigger a function before closing my metro app but I don't know where such as

```
app.onactivated = function (args){
  //all the actions here will be executed on app's activation
}
```

I want something for deactivation or app's closure, what's the proper way to do this in WinJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, it will be onunload event.

"Occurs when the application is about to be unloaded." - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229845.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for both [onunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229845.aspx) and [oncheckpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx). There are differences and you may need one or the other.

Comment: Can you provide links for those? And maybe an example of when to use each?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229774.aspx) really helps when dealing with MS platform.

Comment: I just edited my answer to fix the links to the MSDN documentation. I don't have time to provide examples right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll actually want to tie into the [`WinJS.Application` `unload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229845.aspx) event, which is really just a wrapper for `window.onunload`, but is the "Windows 8" way to do it:

```
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("unload", function(e) {
    // do any needed clean up
});
```